# How does the flex shorthand handle a single value that is represented as a percentage?

Tags: css, flexbox, specifications

The [Mozilla Developer Network `flex` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) says of its syntax:

> **One-value syntax:** the value must be one of:
>
> - a unitless `<number>`: then it is interpreted as `<flex-grow>`.
> - a valid value for width: then it is interpreted as `<flex-basis>`.
> - one of the keyword values `none`, `auto`, or `initial`.

The second bullet implies that `flex: 20%;` is equivalent to `flex-basis: 20%;`, as `20%` is a valid value for `width`.

However, that is not the case in practice:

1. [`flex` shorthand](https://jsfiddle.net/0y86qc24/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container>div {
  padding: 6px;
}

.one {
  background: #fcc9e5;
  flex: 20%;
}

.two {
  background: #ecaef9;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
</div>
```

2. [`flex-basis`](https://jsfiddle.net/0y86qc24/1/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container>div {
  padding: 6px;
}

.one {
  background: #fcc9e5;
  flex-basis: 20%;
}

.two {
  background: #ecaef9;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
</div>
```

So, what is happening here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property) says that, in a `flex` shorthand declaration, when `<flex-grow>` and `<flex-shrink>` are omitted, they both default to 1. ([MDN incorrectly states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex#Values) that `<flex-grow>` defaults to 0.)

This means that the shorthand declaration `flex: 20%` is equivalent to `flex: 1 1 20%`.

Specifying only `flex-basis: 20%` leaves `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` at their initial values of 0 and 1 respectively, making that longhand declaration by itself equivalent to the shorthand `flex: 0 1 20%`.

Comment: I'm not sure if MDN is incorrect. Or the spec is incorrect. Or the spec is just confusing, because there is an apparent contradiction between the definition table and the definition text in the spec.

Comment: @Michael_B: There is no contradiction; the statement "When omitted, it is set to 1." appears in the flex shorthand section, and therefore applies only when the flex shorthand is specified (with a missing flex-grow factor). When the flex shorthand is not specified, flex-grow retains its initial value of 0.

Comment: @Michael_B: This also implies that `flex: 20%; flex-grow: initial` (in that order) will result in flex-grow being 0, through normal cascade resolution, and similarly for `flex: 20%` in a less specific rule and `flex-grow: initial` in a separate but more specific rule.

Comment: The spec says the Initial Value of `flex` is `0 1 auto`. This implies that if `flex-grow` is omitted, its value would be `0`. However, the same definition later states that if `flex-grow` is omitted, its value is `1`. I think that's a bit confusing. It also breaks with the pattern of Initial Value definitions for other properties.

Comment: @Michael_B: The reason the initial value is specified this way is because flex is a shorthand property. If it only specified the initial value to be auto, it would expand to 1 1 auto, as described by the normative text. This is mentioned in §7.1.1 (which is informative, but completely consistent with the normative text).

Comment: Ah, yes. There's an explanation at the bottom of 7.1.1. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the flex shorthand handle a single value that is represented as a percentage?

Very simple. Like this:

- `flex: 20%`

Is equivalent to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 20%`

The people at MDN have apparently misinterpreted [the `flex` definition in the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property), which is actually a bit confusing.

On the one hand, the spec says the ***Initial Value*** for `flex` is `flex: 0 1 auto`.

[image]

But if you read the text right below, it says ([as pointed out by @BoltClock in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45439795/3597276)), that the value for `flex-grow` is `1` when omitted.

[image]

So, bottom line, in your first example, `flex: 20%` is equivalent to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 20%`

While in your second example, `flex-basis: 20%` is equivalent to:

- `flex-grow: 0` (the initial value)
- `flex-shrink: 1` (the initial value)
- `flex-basis: 20%`

By the way, this is exactly why the flexbox specification makes this recommendation:

> **Authors are encouraged to control flexibility using the `flex` shorthand rather than with its longhand properties directly, as the shorthand correctly resets any unspecified components to accommodate [common uses](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common).**
>
> *<sup>https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-components</sup>*